# Align environment doesn't like defined indices

Tags: align, amsmath

The following Latex code doesn't compile. It seems that the align environment does not like the index `\split`. 
What is the reason for this behavior and how can I make align use such indices?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def \split{\mathrm{split}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\int_{A_\split}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Closing brace is missing in `\split` definition

Comment: Yes, but the problem persists.

Comment: I think `\split` is forbidden, try with `\int_{A_\text{split}}`

Comment: if you had used the latex syntax `\newcommand` you would have have had an error at the definition. If you use `\def` you avoid that check but you redefine `amsmath` internals with no checks, so after that anything that happens is up to you.

Comment: @Ignasi: Yes sure, but that's inconvenient, and I want to know what exactly is forbidden and why.

Comment: `split` is a defined environment, then I suppose (just a guess) you cannot use as a command. If you don't want to type `A_\text{split}`, define the subindex with another name: `\newcommand{\splt}{\text{split}}`, it will work: `A_\splt`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\split` is the internal definition of the `split` environment, and in order to give `split` its special properties when nested inside `align` and similar constructs, the definition of `\split` is adjusted in those environments. So inside `align` the original definition is used, not your definition.

`\def` is not intended to be used in LaTeX documents for exactly this reason. Had you used

```
\newcommand\split{\mathrm{split}}
```

then the error would have been detected earlier, that you were redefining `amsmath` internals.

Answer (score 2):

There exist already a command \split, if you change it to e.g. \spl it will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def \spl{\mathrm{split}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\int_{A_{\spl}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```